# Sqlalchemy queries are running on snowflake but not consistently returning data

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When executing queries through a sqlalchemy connection to Snowflake, only a small number return data. The other times, an Operational Error is thrown from the connection.

However, looking at the query_history of my user through the webUI, it shows that the query itself was run and the data produced (rows extracted > 0). However this data was not returned through the connection.

Is there some temporary table where this data is being stored, or further requirements for a snowflake connection that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason might be that you have not whitelisted access to snowflake maintained customer internal stage area. This area is used to place large data sets and pull up in the tool when requested.

You can possibly use the whitelisting function and validate if the access is present from your network.

Link [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html#system-whitelist) has more information for the whitelisting function.

Hope this helps!